# Efficient computation of the value-at-risk of a credit portfolio via summation of independent discrete random variables

Tags: random-variable, risk, sum

With the application of computing a value-at-risk for a credit portfolio (tail percentile of a distribution) in mind, I am currently contemplating the possibility of estimating the distribution tail of a sum of independent discrete random variables $X_i$ that can take as value either $0$ or $L_i > 0$, with probabilities $(1-p_i)$ and $p_i$ respectively and where, typically, $p_i < 0.10$ for the problem at hand. The $p_i$ (probability of default) and $L_i$ (amount of loss) are known in advance but can vary from one run to the other as portfolios evolve with time.

Thus, in short, I am looking for 
$$\alpha = \rm{F}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i \leq VaR_\alpha\right),$$
where $\alpha \in \{0.975, 0.99, 0.999\}$, $F$ is the cumulative distribution function, and $N$ can be of the order of thousands.

My first trial was by numerical convolution to estimate the distribution resulting from the sum. However, this method rapidly proves unsuited for growing N as the number of non-zero values possibly taken by $\sum_i X_i$ quickly grows with $N$ and memory issues rapidly arise in Matlab (the tool I have at my disposal).

I have seen a number of posts related to the estimation of the distribution of sum of independent variables but none seemed to direclty apply to my problem as they either assumed the $p_i$ to not being too small, focused on the center of the distribution, or required the use of a computer algebra system which I do not have access to.

Any ideas, hints, help on the matter will be warmly welcome.

Comment: -1: Your definition of \alpha is incorrect!
To start try to read a book about risk management such as Quantitative Risk Management by "Alexander J. McNeil, Paul Embrechts, and Rüdiger Frey"

Comment: @g g: I updated the formulation to a more conventional notation though it does not change the underlying computational issue.

Comment: This is a standard problem well covered in textbooks, such as the one I mentioned above (Chapter 8, "Credit Risk Management"). Try googling "Monte Carlo method" and "importance sampling". And by the way it is not considered appropriate to assume the $X_i$ to be independent.